# How do I put dropzone.js box to an existing form in my html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I am working with laravel. I need put dropzone.js image upload box in to my existing form. normally dropzone comes with form tag and drozone class like this,

```
<form action="/file-upload"
      class="dropzone"
      id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

but I need add dropzone box in to my existing form and save all other data with images using one submit buttons. do you have any idea to configure this?
**update**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>

<div>I need put dropzone here</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropzone is a very extensible library. it allows use to make any div a dropzone.
If you don't want to use form - you can make a dropzone programatically using -

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
```

if you are using native javascript. And if you are using jquery you can use -

```
$("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
```

Comment: I need little bit explain, I am new web development technology. I have some sample form in my updated question. please note me how can I put drozone there as your answer

Comment: ok, I got where should I put My drpzone box, but I have no an idea where should I put **var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});** and **$("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });**

Comment: ok got it finaly what is ({ url: "/file/post" }) is this image storing path in my application?

Comment: can i use this same url

Comment: ok, it is working but have some problem. that is My uploaded images preview with cross mark. not display correct mark that means it is not uploaded to the server? how to fix this?

Comment: you gotta handle the request.. and this is not how stackoverflow works. You gotta ask for help not complete solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic